# Ingress not working on Kubernetes Infrastructure

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, kubernetes-ingress

I created a microservices infrastructure on Kubernetes (version: 1.20.9-gke.1001) on Google Cloud Platform using the Spring Cloud.

First I created the following deployments: Eureka (service discovery), Zuul (API Gateway), Zipkin (Distributed tracing system), User Service and Auth Service.

Then I created the following services: eureka-service with “Cluster IP” type which allows other pods to connect to Eureka, zipkin-service with “Cluster IP” type which allows other pods to connect to Zipkin and loadbalancer-service with “External load balancer” type which is connected to the Zuul.

Finally I tried to create an Ingress using the attached yaml file but at every request I tried to execute, I received the following error: “response 404 (backend NotFound), service rules for the path non-existent”. While if I try to invoke the APIs using the external IP of the loadbalancer-service the backend works correctly.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: project-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: project.test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: loadbalancer-service
            port:
              number: 8765
```

Do you have any idea why the Ingress is not working?

Also I would need to expose the services with HTTPS, could you kindly explain to me how to use an existing security certificate in the Ingress?

Thanks, this is my first experience with Kubernetes and of course any advice on how to improve the infrastructure is welcome.

Comment: whats the output of kubectl get endpoints? does the loadbalancer-service has endpoints associated with it?

Comment: @meaningqo I ran the command you recommended which returned me that the loadbalancer-service has associated the IP 10.52.1.8:8765